# Number of possible ways for a group of ratings to give a specified average

Tags: combinatorics

This is a combinatorial counting problem I'm trying to solve just for my own curiosity, but the obvious approach (in my mind) balloons into a multi-dimensional nightmare very quickly.

Say you work for a service, and customers can give you a rating. The rating scale is 1..5, with 5 as best. They have 24 hours to rate you, and after that they can't. You don't get to see the individual ratings, but you can see the average rating over the past 24 hours. You only know you got somewhere between 1 and 'n' ratings that resulted in the current average, where 'n' is the number of customers you've had in the past 24 hours. (Some people rate immediately, some wait a bit, and some never get around to it.)

Here's the problem: given an average rating and the maximum number of possible ratings (ie., customers) over the past 24 hours, what are the different combinations of ratings that could have been given that will produce that exact average rating value? Also, historically speaking, it's very rare for 100% of customers to give ratings; the average is around 60%-70%.

If it helps, assume there won't be more than 20 possible ratings in any 24 hour period. Also, assume the average never drops below 4.0 -- that is, most ratings are 5's. The question is, what's the possible distribution of non-5 ratings for any given average?

Example: you had 10 customers in the past 24 hours, and you have an average rating of 4.67. What are the possible ratings that could have produced that average? (I got that average with three ratings of: 5, 5, and 4.) The question is, how can one discover all possible rating combinations that produce a 4.67 average with a max of 10 possible ratings?

Perhaps I should add that the norm is 5. So 5s pull the average up, while everything else pulls it down.

The rating is always given as a floating point number with at most two decimals: 4.xx

Comment: Hi David. Welcome to MSE! the convention to get help from other people is to also write down your thoughts besides the question. So please do so. The question has a familiar format. Has it taken from any kind of coding competitions out there? if so, you should mention that as well.

Comment: Without any help concerning the main question, I just can say that rating distribution tends to normal (Bell curve).

Comment: I'm a programmer, and this is how I write. It's simply a problem I'm dealing with that I'm curious how to solve. I have a degree in Math and Computer Science, but I was never very good with combinatorics.

Comment: The rating distribution is not a bell curve. It can drop below 4 periodically, but the long-term average is between 4 and 5.

Comment: David, please make the title of the question more informative. Regards,

Comment: Suggestions are welcome

Comment: I like that title. Thanks to whomever changed it!

Comment: It would help if you highlighted the actual setup of the problem in the text. Currently there is a lot of irrelevant information that makes it difficult to pull out the details of the setup. If you are looking for a mathematical solution, "if it helps assume $<20$" is irrelevant, "historically speaking..." sentence is irrelevant, and I think "24 hours" is irrelevant since all the action happens in one 24 hour time period. I assume all the ratings are integers. Is the number of customers known, or does the "number of ways" include varying this parameter?

Comment: Sorry, it looks like I mis-copied something. (5,5,4) results in 4.67 average rating.

Comment: It's a mushy problem with lots of variables that I figured would result in the kinds of divergent answers that are showing up here. There's also a time dimension that I'm going to add a note to below. Hey, it's a real-world problem! I'm just describing it as it occurs to me, which I'm sure isn't as clean or clear as hard-core mathematicians would like. ;) But I do appreciate all of the questions and comments.

Answer (score 1):

(This is not an answer in the proper sense. It just introduces the relevant variables, given the data.)

Denote by $x_k\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$ $\>(1\leq k\leq5)$ the number of times grade $k$ has been given, by $\lambda$ the average grade, and by $n$ the number of customers in the last 24 hours. Then
$$\lambda={\sum_{k=1}^5 k\>x_k \over\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k}\ .$$
It follows that the $x_k$ satisfy the conditions
$$\sum_{k=1}^5(k-\lambda) x_k=0, \qquad\sum_{k=1}^5 x_k\leq n\ .$$
Note that $\lambda$ may be not known exactly. Given that $n\leq20$ and $\geq60\%$ of the customers respond there are about
$${1\over5!}\bigl(20^5-14^5)\doteq22\,000\tag{1}$$
lattice points to check. The  expression $(1)$ represents the volume of the set $$\{(x_1,\ldots, x_5)\in{\mathbb R}^5\>|\>x_k\geq0, \ 14\leq x_1+\ldots+ x_5\leq 20\}\ .$$

Comment: That's n <= 20 and <= 60% of customers respond. But often n < 10. This is a mushy problem. And it's a real problem. I see the current average rating and I wonder what individual ratings went into it. Given an exact decimal and the fact that all ratings are integers, and the total counts are always fairly small, it seems fairly reasonable to guess at the ratings.

Comment: What would this solution look like if you take into account the fact that you need a range $[\lambda-0.005,\lambda+0.005]$ instead of $\lambda$ given the rounding?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter: Can you please explain why $20^5$? I would have said $5^{20}$ (5 possibilities for each voter). Thanks,

Comment: @borisd There are only $5$ vectors, each of which contains a number less than $n$ (this is counting how many people voted $5$, how many gave $4$, etc.), so the number of possibilities is bounded by $n^5$.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Thank you. I now see where the $14^5$ come from, but not $\frac{1}{5!}$?

Comment: If someone has a bit of time, can i get some help understanding Christian's reasonning? I would have done this way: the number of possibilities to partition $20$ elements in $5$ sets is $(^{24}_4)$ (=number of possible ratings for 20 voters). So the total number of possible ratings of from $14$ to $20$ voters is $\sum_{k=14}^{20} (^{k+4}_4)=44562$. I suppose that there is a way to filter at least half of these which would yield to wrong average ratings, leading to the same result as Christian, but his reasonning seems totally different. Can someone help?

Comment: @borisd I expanded on the method used here in my own answer, which shows the $n^4$ dependence even more clearly. Note that a binomial coefficient with $4$ on the bottom is of order $O(n^4)$; summing it gives $O(n^5)$ which is what you would expect given the size of the base lattice (the extra $n$ comes from the fact that you are ignoring the restriction on average). As for the $\frac1{5!}$, my guess is because the region of interest is not a $5$-D hypercube but a $5$-simplex (high-dimensional triangle), whose volume is much smaller.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Thank you, it is more clear now. I was mislead by not taking into account the fact that the number of possible individual rates is fixed to a constant.

Answer (score 1):

(Borrowing the setup from Cristian's answer:) Denote by $x_k\in{\mathbb N}_{\geq0}$ $\>(1\leq k\leq5)$ the number of times grade $k$ has been given, by $\lambda^*$ the true average grade and $\lambda$ the rounded average grade, and by $n$ the number of customers in the last 24 hours, and let $\lambda^+=\lambda+.005$, $\lambda^-=\lambda-.005$ (these are the bounds on the true average grade). Also, let $s=\sum_{k=1}^5x_k\le n$ be the number of voters. Then:
$$\lambda^-s\le\sum_{k=1}^5 k\>x_k\le\lambda^+s.$$

This constraint on $\lambda$ severely limits the number of possibilities for $s$, because $s\lambda^*$ is an integer and $s\lambda$ is close to an integer, and since $s$ is fairly small we can correct for this inexactitude. So our first step is to find integers $s,T=s\lambda^*$ that satisfy $\operatorname{round}(T/s)=\lambda$. If you are programming this you can just check that $\lfloor s\lambda^-\rfloor \ne\lfloor s\lambda^+\rfloor$ for each candidate $s$ - any number which does not satisfy this cannot be a possibility. For example, for $\lambda=4.67$ we see that for $s=1$ this gives $[4.665,4.675]$ which does not contain an integer, $s=2$ gives $[9.33,9.35]$ which does not contain an integer, and $s=3$ gives $[13.995,14.025]$ which contains $T=14$. This reflects the fact that $4.67$ is probably rounded from $4+2/3=14/3$.

After fixing integers $s,T$ by this search, we can list the lattice points that satisfy this total value. First we need to find one point on the lattice; if $4\le\lambda^*\le 5$ we can use $b=(0,0,0,5s-T,T-4s)$, which you can check satisfies $\sum_ix_i=s$ and $\sum_iix_i=T$ (this says that everyone votes $4$ or $5$, with the proportions calibrated to give the right average).

From this basepoint, we can use the three lattice generators:

$$v^1=(3,-4,0,0,1)\qquad v^2=(2,-3,0,1,0)\qquad v^3=(1,-2,1,0,0)$$

Note that for each $v^k$, $\sum_iv^k_i=0$ and $\sum_iiv^k_i=0$. Thus adding $v^k$ to a lattice point yields another lattice point, and since this is a $5$-dimensional system reduced by two equations, and these vectors are clearly independent, this gives all the lattice points.

The only issue is how far to go. We've just seen that $b+n_1v^1+n_2v^2+n_3v^3$ is a solution for any $n_k\in\Bbb Z$, but this doesn't take into account the nonnegativity constraints on the $x_i$'s. I won't go into details, but it's not hard to verify that a solution is nonnegative iff it satisfies $$4s-T\le n_1\le\frac34(5s-T),\qquad T-5s\le n_2\le-\frac43n_1,\\\max(0,-3n_1-2n_2)\le n_3\le-\frac12(4n_1+3n_2),$$ and it's not difficult to simply enumerate all integer triples satisfying these inequalities. This yields a complete enumeration of the solutions in roughly $O(n^4)$ steps, where $n$ is the upper bound on $T$ here, which is proportional to our original $n$ for the number of customers that could have voted.

Comment: Is there a typo in the text: vector $b$ and vectors $v$ are not read in the same directions (in $b$, first component is for rate $1$, and in $v^1$ for $5$)?
Independently, I have a doubt concerning the generators. The signs of $v_5^1$ and $v_1^1$ are the same; and $v_1^1$ has a non-null value only in $v^1$. Does that mean that, in any vector $w$ generated from $b$, either both $w_1$ and $w_5$ are not larger than $b_1$ and $b_5$, or both not smaller?
Suppose that $T=91$ and $b=(0,0,0,4,15)$. How can we generate $w=(0,1,1,4,14)$ which is another possible rating set? Thank you,

Comment: @borisd Regarding order of $v^k$, I don't believe it is reversed; for example I calculate $3-2\cdot 4+5\cdot 1=0$ for the net rating change from $v^1$. However, since each $v^k$ satisfies $\sum_i(6-i)x_i=6\sum_ix_i-\sum_iix_i=0$, it is no coincidence that the vectors are still solutions if the components are reversed.

Comment: @borisd As for accessing different solutions via the generators, note that the $v^k$ vectors only give you more solutions with the *same* $s,T$ values - these are fixed in advanced since the rounding presents some nonlinearity. You can get to these by iterating over $s$ and then iterating over all integer values of $T$ between $\lambda^-s$ and $\lambda^+s$ (which for $s<100$ will always be either none or one integer). Your examples have different $s$ values, $19$ in $b$ and $20$ in $w$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $A(i,r,k)$ denote the set of possible rate sets (each rate is encoded as $(x_1,...,x_i)$, $x_j$ being the number of rates $j$) that yield a sum of rates equal to $r$, with possible rates from $1$ to $i$ and $k$ voters.

You can write the following recursive relation :
$$
A(i,r,k)=\cup_{i.l \le r,l\le k} \left( A(i-1,r-l.i,k-l) \times \{x_i=l\} \right)
$$
$$
A(0,0,0)=\emptyset
$$

where $\times$ is the cartesian product. You can use this relation to compute the set for all $(i,r,k)$ such that $R.k=r, i=5, 0 \le k \le n$, $R$ being the given average rate.

To be efficient, do not use a recursive algorithm, but rather a dynamic-programming like algorithm (start with $i=k=r=0$, and compute $A(i,k,r)$ using the values of $A$ for smaller parameters already computed and stored).

Edit: depending on the number of possible voters, computing $A$ for all smaller values of $(i,r,k)$ may not be the most efficient. One can consider a recursive approach storing all values of $A$ already computed in a hash map for example.

Edit 2: As explained by @MarioCarneiro, the number of solutions is polynomial in the number of possible voters (since the number of possible individual rates being a fixed constant). It follows that a simple 5-nested loops procedure would do the job.

Comment: Does this recursive relation on rate sets yield a recursive relation for $|A|$ which does not require keeping track of the rate sets themselves?

Comment: This looks nice in theory, but as a programmer, it looks like overkill. How many combinations of 5s, 4s, 3s, 2s and 1s can result in a given average rating of, say, 4.5, with no more than 10 possible ratings -- which you know is probably capped at 60% (or 6) as a real max rating count? I'm not going to start at the minimum and work up, but at the maximum and work down, because I know the majority of ratings will be 5s and 4s most of the time. Again it's not a bell curve. Some days you get eight 5s out of 12 possible ratings, for an average of 5 (which is indistinguishable from one 5).

Comment: The question was to generate all possible ratings. They are in exponential number, so no surprise the algorithm does not run in polytime. If you want to get all possible ratings, you cannot use statistical uncertain assumptions? Heuristically, you may still limit the value of $l$ for low rates. If you go top-down, you can still cache the values to fasten the recursion.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: yes you could proceed in a two pass algorithm. The first one just computes the parameters for which $A(i,r,k)$ is not empty. The second one actually computes the sets, knowing that most of parameters combinations are useless. 
@ David Schwartz: This can be a start of a solution to the combinatorial explosion?

Comment: Looks like Christian's answer above solves the exponential blowup problem by not counting $(5,5,4)$ and $(4,5,5)$ as distinct (which adds a ${n\choose k}$-type term to the number of solutions). That way it's only a $5$-dimensional space and so the number of lattice points is polynomial.

Comment: I don't care about the ordering. (5,5,4), (5,4,5), and (4,5,5) are equivalent AFAIC.

Comment: @MarioCarneiro: I am not sure to understand. My proposition stores (5,5,4) and (4,5,5) as $(x_5=2,x_4=1)$ (no ordering), so I do not think it more expensive? Anyway, the set to be enumerated is of exponential size. It seems to me that Christian's answer does not enumerate the whole specific set of ratings corresponding to the average rate and solves a slightly different problem. Regards,

Comment: Ok, let me throw one more monkey wrench into the mix. This can actually help. As I said, the ratings come in over a 24-hour period. Some are sooner, some are later. If I refresh the screen, I can see the average rating change. So it might go from 5 to 4.67, to 4.75. This gives a set of points that suggests data and an ordering: 5, 5, 4, 5. So if I record the changes in the average rating over several hours, it leaves a trail that narrows the following choices after each change. 5,5 = 5. Then 4.67 can only be from a couple of options. Then 4.75 is again only from one option.

Comment: continued ... so if I record the changes in the rating over time, this might make it a lot easier to narrow the choices at each step and yield not only a simpler solution, but even an ordering. It turns out that 5 is the norm, so 5s pull the average up, and everything else pulls it down. One 3 can look like two 4s, except if I capture the rating at successive intervals, it can actually distinguish between one 3 and two 4s.

Answer (score 0):

This is the answe explaining one posible aproach you can use to solve your problem that I tried to post on Stack Owerflow before your question has been put on hold.

If you asume that all votes are either 4 or 5 then the answer is pretty simple. All you have to do is reverse the process that you use in calculation of average value.

You calculate average by using next approach.

```
AverageOfVotes = SumOfAllVotes / NumberOfVotes
```

So you should reverse this in order to get SumOfAllVotes value out

```
SumOfAllVotes = AverageOfVotes * NumberOfVotes
```

Now when you have SumOfAllVotes available you calculate its difference between maximum possilbe sum of votes which would be

```
MaximumSumOfVotes = NumberOfVotes * MaximumVoteValue //In your case 5
```

So if you asume that all votes are only 4 or 5 you can also asume that number of 4 votes is the same as the difference between maximum sum of votes and your current sum of votes. The rest of votes are 5.

So if we check your example of three votes (5,5 and 4)

```
Average = SumOfVotes / NumberOfVotes
Average = (5+5+4) / 3
Average = 14 / 3
Average = 4,666666666666667

Reversing the process

SumOfVotes = Average * NumberOfVotes

SumOfVotes = 4,666666666666667 * 3
SumOfVotes = 14

NumberOf4Votes = MaximumSomofVotes - SumOfVotes
NumberOf4Votes = (NumberOfVotes * maximumVoteValue) - SumOfVotes
NumberOf4Votes = (3 * 5) - 14
NumberOf4Votes = 15 - 14
numberOf4Votes = 1
```

But as soon as the posible votes are 3, 4 and 5 or even 1 and 2 this becomes much more complex. Why? Becouse there are multiple vote combinations that would result in same SumOfVotes. But the overal process would be still the same.

I hope my answer makes any sense to you.

Comment: Yes, it's that last bit you mention that messes things up and creates a multi-dimensional nightmare. Overall, 70% or more of the ratings are 5s. The rest are usually 4s. Sometimes there will be a lower rating, although they are rare. If you think about all possible combinations, the vast majority are never seen. It's impossible to distinguish any number of 5s, but if there's just one 4, you can actually determine how many ratings there were if it's fairly small (eg. < 20). The more non-5 ratings you get, the more possible solutions there are. But again, for n<20 (usually <10) it's manageable.

Comment: Actuaslly the greater the number of posible votes the more difficult it becomes becouse different combination of them can result in same sum. For instance average of votes 5,4,4 is same as average of votes 5,5,3 so you end up with multiple results. So this means that it is practically inposible to calculate the exact number of votes in such scenario.

Comment: Yes, but see my two comments above regarding capturing the average rating over time. It helps to resolve this.

Comment: FWIW, 4.6 is the bottom-end acceptable long-term average, meaning  92% or more of my ratings must be 5s. The mean rating for the statistical community I'm in is something like 4.65. My long-term average is 4.7, which I'm told is "above average". We don't get to see individual ratings, but we can see the average of ratings given over the past 24 hours, which can be updated at any time. It drives me nuts that my rating bounces around as much as it does, so I'm really curious about ways to correlate it more closely with actual events that are fresh in my mind.